# jsonp callback function not recognized

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I've an ajax called like

```
$.ajax({
    url: getURL,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { url: url, token: token },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "getJSONP",
    success: function () { /* do something */ },
    error: function() { console.log('Failed!'); }
});
```

and a the `jsonpCallback` function as

```
function getJSONP(data) {
    console.log(data.content);
}
```

On the dev console, I see it's returned properly

[image]

However I still get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: getJSONP is not defined`. How should I fix this?

Comment: just let jQuery manage the callback internally. WHat happens when you comment out that property?

Comment: Can you confirm that getJSONP is not scope limited?

Comment: @charlietfl, if I remove it completely, the default callback seems to be identified as `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery20009755692519247532_1452925821322 is not defined`; @saqib, I assume the way I've defined makes it Global.

Comment: never seen this problem...create a demo that replicates it. BTW...when you use a string....it isn't requiring a real function, that value will be used internally to parse the data, if you pass it a function then you need to return the response from that function

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the API I'm calling to? https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser#idm386426510528